# Removing whitespace beneath footer with CSS (Wordpress)

Tags: html, css, footer

I just revamped my website and I'm having a bit of trouble with the fine details (keep in mind that I know almost nothing about web development, even though I'm in the software field; I'm trying to learn).

Namely, I noticed on some of my smaller pages (my About page, for example) have a white bar going across the screen underneath the footer. I'd much rather have the footer dynamically extend itself to the bottom of the screen. How can I do this, can I write some custom CSS?

Here's my site:
http://frankpernice.com/resume/

Comment: You basically need a sticky footer. Your issue isn't a bug or anything. It's rendering as it's supposed to.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/ this should do what you're looking for.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 I understand that, but I didn't write any of the code except for some unrelated custom CSS; it's a Wordpress theme. If this makes it any better, here's the theme I'm using: https://wordpress.org/themes/avocation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to flexbox, sticky footers (including those without a fixed height - because hardly anything that is responsive can have a fixed height) have become dead simple (depending on the markup of your page). Fortunately, your markup is excellent for it:

```
html,body { height:100%; }
body { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
body>section { flex: 1 0 auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to fixed poistion ;-)

```
.footer-bg {
    position: relative;
}

.footer-bg {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: This sorta works, but now it blocks some content that was on the bottom of my larger pages

Comment: @audiFanatic that is normal.. a minute please.. (lots of work here)

Comment: @audiFanatic you approved answer so i'm not going to add more work into this.. if still needed let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Aibrean is correct, you need to use a sticky footer similar to that proposed in the link here...

http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/

Alternatively you could apply position: fixed; and bottom: 0; to your 'footer' element, but this would bring problems when working with pages that have content that stretches beyond your window height.

Matt

Comment: Please avoid referring to links and post as much of content as you can, as links may not be available later on.